# Is there a formula that can quickly calculate the ByteCount of an integer?

Tags: functions

```
Manipulate[byte = ByteCount[num];
 ListPlot[{{num, byte}}, 
  PlotLabel -> Text[Style[Row[{"ByteCount", " : ", byte}], 12]], 
  PlotRange -> All], {{num, 0, "num"}, 0, 10^19
  , 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image: fig1]

The value of byte is always 16, but this is wrong.For example, The result of `ByteCount[10^19]` should be 48.In addition, I want to know how much memory is needed to calculate `10^(100000000000 - 1)` and its `ByteCount`.After preliminary test, the windows system can calculate it when the running memory is greater than 8GB.

Comment: I believe it's computing `ByteCount[10.^19]`, which is 16. Sliders use floating-point, unless the boundary values and increment are a different type.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your opinion seems to be correct.

Comment: The "type" doesn't even have to be numeric. You just need the increment to divide the length of the "interval" evenly: `Manipulate[y, {y, 2 x, 10 x, x}]`. For your application, you should specify an increment that is an integer, which is probably obvious at this point.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ```{num, 0, 10 10^18, 10^18}```This method really works. However, if the growth interval is too large, it is easy to lose the mutation point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this as an alternative:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[
 Table[
  {num, ByteCount[num]},
  {num, PowerRange[10^19]}
  ]
]
```

[image: scatter plot where all bytecounts are 16 except for 10^19 which has ByteCount=48]

Answer (score 4):

I think what's going on here is that the Manipulate automatically converts `num` to a fixed precision floating point number, probably because the step size becomes so small relative to `num`.

I'm assuming that you're not really interested in a ListPlot of a single point, but that that was just an example. So, here's an alternate way:

```
Manipulate[{10^exp, ByteCount[10^exp]}, {{exp, 0, "exponent"}, 0, 30, 1}]
```

Comment: Good answer ! But if the growth interval is too large, it is easy to lose the mutation point.

Comment: So, that's a legitimate observation, but the title of your question was specifically about Manipulate, so I tried to explain the issue and provide an alternative version of Manipulate. Now you seem to be asking how to find the exact integer where byte count jumps. I think we could have gotten to that point a lot quicker if you had just asked that question. And I think that's a completely different question, maybe deserving its own separate post.

Answer (score 3):

```
Table[FromDigits[Table[5, {n}]], {n, 4}]

(*out: {5,55,555,5555}*)
```

plot:

```
DiscretePlot[ByteCount[FromDigits[Table[5, {n}]]], {n, 100}]
```

[image: fig1]

The average rate of increase is about 0.4 bytes per decimal digit:

```
Fit[Table[ByteCount[FromDigits[Table[5, {n}]]], {n, 1000}], {1, n}, n]
(*out: 42.8112 + 0.416841 n*)
```

The above is learned from official documents.

### **update1:**

```
num = 10^18;
While[ByteCount[num] == 16, Print[num]; num++]
```

We can get that the first jump point is {9223372036854775808 , 48}. You can adjust the initial value of `num` to speed up the calculation.

```
Table[{num, ByteCount[num]}, {num, 10^18, 10^19, 10^18}]
```

### **update2:**

```
    exp = 5;
    (Table[Length[IntegerDigits[num, 2]], {num, 10^exp, 10^(exp + 1) - 1, 
          1}] // Mean)/(exp + 1) // N
(*out: 3.21898*)
```

When `exp` tends to infinity, the value of Length ratio is infinitely close to `Log[2, 10]`.

Comment: `Log[2, 10]/8` bytes per decimal digit (about 0.415241).

Comment: @Roman You'd better explain to everyone why it's calculated like this. The modern de facto standard of eight bits is a convenient power of two permitting the binary-encoded values 0 through 255 for one byte. Is it related to this ?

Comment: I think it's clear that the relationship between binary and decimal representations of integers is such that a number with $n$ decimal digits has $n\ln(10)/\ln(2)=n\log_2(10)$ binary digits ("bits"). Divide those by 8 because it's 8 bits per byte.

Comment: Here is the proof process: https://www.exploringbinary.com/ratio-of-bits-to-decimal-digits/

Comment: Your conclusion lacks proof process. This conclusion is not clear to those who are not good at mathematics. as number grows large, there are ```Log[2, 10]``` times as many bits as there are decimal digits. This doesn’t mean that each decimal digit requires ```Log[2, 10]``` bits; it’s just an average across all digits. Related posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1416606/1058269